# special key turn into keybaord number when sendkeys with special in MicrosoftEdgeDrive with protractor

Tags: selenium-webdriver, protractor, microsoft-edge

I am running WebAutomation with protractor and selenium Webdriver.
However i notice when perform a sendkeys action with special key (eg:$)

the input field will receive 4 which is same as number on keyboard.

Is it known issue on protractor ? MicrosoftEdge Driver ? Selenium Web Driver?

Comment: Have you tried sendkeys on different browsers?

Comment: as i run test in multi-browser. i using element.sendkeys('*'); and it worked in chrome, firefox, ie, but not in edge :(

Answer (score 0):

try send the unicode character:

> $ = \u0024

```
element.sendKeys('\u0024');
```

Comment: It worked for other browser, but not for MicrosftEdge. I getting 4 instead of $